# Python write zip into text file

Tags: python, zip, output

How can I write `zip` into a text file?

```
x=[a,b,c,d,e]
y=[1,2,3,4,5]

zipped = zip(x,y)

output = open("out.txt","w")
output.write(zipped)
output.close()
```

I would like to get `a1,b2,c3,d4,e5` but `write()` argument must be `str` not `zip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the desired output:
`result = ','.join([ a+str(b) for (a,b) in zipped ])`
it concatenates the letter and the number into a string and then joins the strings separating them with a comma

---

If you only wanted to create a string from the zip:
`result = ''.join(map(str, zipped))`
which creates a string of each zipped element and then joins them together

---

Answer (score 1):

*you can write this way*

```
x=['a','b','c','d','e']
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
zipped = zip(x,y)
with open('out.txt', 'w') as fp:
     fp.write(''.join('%s%s' % x for x in zipped))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a modern Python version you can use f-string

```
>>> ','.join(f'{i}{j}' for i, j in zip('abcde', range(1,6)))
'a1,b2,c3,d4,e5'
```

On older versions `format` can be used

```
>>> ','.join('{}{}'.format(*p) for p in zip('abcde', range(1,6)))
'a1,b2,c3,d4,e5'
```